# C# Deedle Dataframe compare columns to create new resulting column

Tags: c#, frame, calculated-columns, deedle

Someone put me out of my misery please! I can't see the forest for all those trees. I have a populated Deedle frame which is effectively of type:

`Frame<int, string> MyPopulatedFrame`

I won't bore you with the initial population routine, but it prints out fine with "value1" and "value2" columns, no issues.

```
value1, value2
1,2
10,5
100,200
etc etc
```

I can then add this code to sum the two columns, which also works fine over the whole series:

`MyPopulatedFrame.AddColumn("value1add2", PairOHLCVFrame.GetColumn<double>("value1") + PairOHLCVFrame.GetColumn<double>("value2"));`

It gives me a delightful little calculated column on the end of my frame with the correct value in each of the rows. i.e.

```
value1, value2, value1add2
1,2,3
10,5,15
100,200,300
etc etc
```

What I would really like to do is populate another column with a 1 or 0 dependent upon value1 being greater than value2. The code ought to look something like this:

`MyPopulatedFrame.AddColumn("isValue1GreaterThanValue2", PairOHLCVFrame.GetColumn<double>("value1") > PairOHLCVFrame.GetColumn<double>("value2") ? 1 : 0);`

but that won't even compile. Giving a design time error of:

`"Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Series<int, double>' and 'Series<int, double>'"`

I know the answer to this must be simple, but it's a case of getting there before my laptop lands in the garden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are populating from a collection you can simply compare value1 and value2 and store the result in a series.

```
 var comparedResult = objects.Select(x => x.Value1 > x.Value2? 1:0).ToOrdinalSeries();
    MyPopulatedFrame.AddColumn("IsGreater", comparedResult);
```

If you have need to get value columns from another dataframe then try the below one.

```
  var newList = dfObjects.Rows.Select(x => new { Value1 = x.Value.GetAs<int>("Value1"),
                   Value2 = x.Value.GetAs<int>("Value2")
               }).Observations;
                var comparedResult = newList.Select(x => x.Value.Value1 >= x.Value.Value2 ? 1 : 0).ToOrdinalSeries();
                dfObjects.AddColumn("IsGreater", comparedResult);
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I've crunched it into a line for tidiness, and I'm sure it looks exactly like the line of code I was fiddling with for 3 hours this morning! Sometimes it needs fresh eyes, I appreciate the assistance. I'm populating it at a later point after the initial 2 columns have been in situ for a while, so the final result looks like: MyPopulatedFrame.AddColumn("value1add2", MyPopulatedFrame.Rows.Select(x => x.Value.GetAs<double>("value1") < x.Value.GetAs<double>("value2") ? 1 : 0));

Comment: Sorry, that should correctly read: MyPopulatedFrame.AddColumn("isValue1GreaterThanValue2", MyPopulatedFrame.Rows.Select(x => x.Value.GetAs<double>("value1") < x.Value.GetAs<double>("value2") ? 1 : 0));

Comment: I have not worked much on deedle package, but i tried to find a way to solve your problem.